# Is there any intuitive idea that helps to understand this?

Tags: analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $(E,\parallel \cdot\parallel_E)$ and $(F,\parallel \cdot\parallel_F)$ be normed vector spaces, $A\subset E$ and $f$ a mapping from $A$ into $F$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

**I)** $f$ is continuous.

**II)** $f^{-1}(O)$ is the intersection of $A$ with an open subset of $E$, if $O$ is open in $F$.

I have tried to think of figures or some intuitive idea that would "explain" why these statements are equivalent, but I failed.

Does anybody have some intuitive idea that makes it clear why this happens?

**EDIT:** The definition of continuity is:

$f$ is continuous in $a$ if $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,\forall x\in A:\parallel a-x\parallel_E<\delta\Rightarrow \parallel f(a)-f(x)\parallel_F<\epsilon$

**EDIT 2:** I know the mathematical proof of this, but I would like an intuitive idea of why this occurs. I have heard that a good mathematics has good intuitions of why some theorems are true, that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: The usual (topological) definition of continuity is that the preimage of any open set is open, in which case the equivalence is trivial. So perhaps clarify what definition of continuity you are working with.

Comment: @Y.Forman I put the definition of continuity.

Comment: "In mathematics you do not understand things. You just get used to them"--John von Neumann.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If John Von Neumann said that, then I believe it!

Comment: It was preceded by the words "Young man..." as he was addressing a student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\epsilon$ in the continuity definition gives a neighborhood of $f(a)$ (intuitively, think open set); the $\delta$ in the continuity definition gives a corresponding neighborhood of $a$ (again, think open set) which maps into the first neighborhood, i.e., is in the preimage.

So the definitions convey roughly the same idea: that given some neighborhood of $f(a)$, there's a neighborhood of $a$ in its preimage.

Comment: Believe it or not now that makes sense to me. Thank you!